# Typescript typing correlated types

Tags: typescript

I have the following types and conversion function:

```
type LeftRightField = null |
    { left: null, right: number } |
    { left: number, right: null } |
    { left: number, right: number }

type LeftRightArray = [null, number] |
    [number, null] |
    [number, number] |
    null

const fmtField = function (field: LeftRightField): LeftRightArray {
    const rightField = field?.right ?? null
    const leftField = field?.left ?? null
    return (leftField == null && rightField == null) ? null : [leftField, rightField]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhBmwBKBLA5gC2AMRRANgCZQC8UAdgK775QA%20AsAFBStQDeU%20CwAXBdXwAaKACd0WflQC2AIwiioAX3rM2HLjymU5CkeMx8BNZapZtO3RNt2j9EozPmKlzZqEiweqQwEFRogCGIKRQANpUNCJOCgC6ZuoROs7RgvGM5qxJtqm26WpskfhuTADGAPbkAM7AUPDSOHhEofCU5KXAKJVQABTwTYT8cIg%20WLgEhACUQ94O-kEh7AWsFdW1BmMDLQMA-AB0G7U7O8bFmVCrNZqI481k-RP7VkcnRctiEMCUouS9z7fEEhkIpQABkoLEDgBpGBgkmUFegig-DC-wG9kMANizCUQA)

However this fails with

> Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'null'

What is the correct way to do the conversion ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an instance of TypeScript not being able to keep track of what I've been calling [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  In your case, `leftField` and `rightField` are both of the union type `number | null`.  Unfortunately, the compiler does not consider them *together* when you do type guards.  It treats them as *uncorrelated*, so `[leftField, rightField]` is seen as type `[number | null, number | null]` even though the `[null, null]` subtype is an impossibility.

The only "right" thing to do here, other than just giving up and [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that what you are doing is safe like this:

```
return (leftField === null && rightField === null) ? null :
 [leftField, rightField] as LeftRightArray;
```

would be to refactor the code into possibly-redundant separate code paths that the compiler can verify with [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010):

```
return (leftField === null) ? (
 rightField === null ? null : [leftField, rightField]
) : [leftField, rightField];
```

If you're just using two fields this is fine.  If you're using many more than that, the redundancy is probably too much and you should just assert and move on.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhBmwBKBLA5gC2AMRRANgCZQC8UAdgK775QA+AsAFADeU+CwAXBdfgDRQATuiw8qAWwBGEIVAC+9Zmw6JxlabMEjM3XjQVLW7Tus1DtovZJlz5zZqEixOqXQEEhQgIYhSUAG0qGkEbWQBdIyCNW1C+SLooZmjzOPME5igs-XwHJgBjAHtyAGdgKHgJHDwif3hKcnzgFGKoAAp4GsIeOEQ3LFwCQgBKHtcrTx8-FkzsotLynQGuuq6AfgA6JfK1tZzZrPmyk0RB2rJOoc3VHb3g3KZs4QhgSiFydpuz4hJfnKgAGQA4RWb6kP73YZQO58KA8AJfLqWXTfcLMexMZhHcqVapDdwlEqycoXBpNFofDpdMZ9UFdUYuWkeLy+KAzR5zYrHbZgi7rLZWaEwmgHKDYk5484Vfk3IX7DlZIQvN6UxFDcFke6A4E8la-TV8KHC2jwtVEZHLIaRbwlRnICYskAAbnReXFuO+SAQ3iahTkpMazVaVKGNPtKPpYf6wEmrPZT3FuvVfKuAt0cvuovFZp+0tTst28qeSte70+nF5EMN0PaSfOVYMxrhgRzFslhHCUNNFaRIIjVpdTAxzCAA)